# Collapse UINavigationBar like Facebook or Safari?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar

I have several `UIViewController`s in my app -- particularly one that displays web content in a `UIWebView` -- that would benefit from being able to collapse the height of a `UINavigationBar`, like you find when you scroll in the Facebook app or Safari on iOS.  However, I can't for the life of me figure out how this is done.

I recognize that I probably need to key off the UIScrollViewDelegate `scrollViewDidScroll`: method, but have not had much success up to this point.  Can anyone give me some pointers on how I can accomplish this?  I did see the [AMScrollingNavbar](https://github.com/andreamazz/AMScrollingNavbar) project, but I can't use it in our app due to company requirements.

Comment: As far as I know AMScrollingNavbar is open source so you could look into their code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the creator of AMScrollingNavbar.
As you can see from the code, I found out that the best way to implement that behavior is to use a gesture recognizer. It's key to implement its delegate protocol, returning YES for the method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

As for the `UIWebView`, remember that you have to deal with the scrollview *contained* in the webview.
You can find more in the source code though, and since I released it under MIT license, feel free to include it in your commercial project, or modify it as you see fit.

I also published an article on the process that I used to create the library, you can read it here:
[AMScrollingNavbar: Creating a Cocoapod](http://andreamazz.github.io/blog/2014/02/01/amscrollingnavbar-creating-a-cocoapod/).

It explains a couple of gotchas that I encountered while writing the library.

Hope this helps.
Cheers